# Upside down caret

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
 <span class="caret"></span>
```

Gives me a caret arrow `▼`, but I want to have a caret that looks like `▲`.

Is there any class for this available in Bootstrap? If not, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There is a built in bootstrap class that you can attach to the parent element of the caret class

```
<span class="dropup">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</span>
```

It works in both bootstrap 2 and 3

Comment: I wish they simplify it to `<span class="caret caret-dropup"></span>`

Answer (score 70):

Let's assume that you want to reverse the caret using the class `caret-reversed`, so that you keep the existing implementation of the `caret` class.

The CSS would be the following.

```
<span class="caret caret-reversed"></span> 

.caret.caret-reversed {
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
}
```

It works both for bootstrap 2 and 3.

**Update**: Since Bootstrap 3.3.2  the `.glyphicon-triangle-top` and `.glyphicon-triangle-bottom` glyphicons are available that can work as alternatives to `.caret` and its reversed version.

**Normal**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
```

**Reversed**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
```

Comment: Use of embedded "dropup" class (as mentioned by Ron below) seems preferred

Comment: Sure, using something already provided by the framework is generally preferred, but in this case one has to use 2 `span` elements instead of one, and that could bloat the HTML code.

Comment: @TasosK., `<span class="caret caret-reversed"></span>` css: `border:Xpx solid transparent; border-bottom:Xpx solid black;` x for whatever value..

Comment: This is very useful when you want to just toggle the caret class

Comment: the only downside to this answer is the css coloring, I think

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add add new css class for up arrow

```
<style>
 .caret-up{
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;
    border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
  }
```

```
<span class="caret-up"></span>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tbgXj/3/

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

in HTML:

```
<span class="caret caret-reversed"></span>
```

in CSS:

```
.caret-reversed{
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and the best solution for me was to edit the styling for bootstrap original so I get the one I needed.

So for everyone that use bootstrap one here is the opposite:

```
.caret-up {
display: inline-block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin-left: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
border-bottom: 4px dashed;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but this is all one needs to do for an upside down caret:

```
.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu > .menu-item-has-children::after {
    content: "\005E";
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    <!-- and any other styles u want -->
}
```

[image: How to add an upside down caret on a psuedo element 'after' button]

Answer (score 0):

**Toggle the caret class**

```
<span class="caret caret-reversed"></span> 

.caret.caret-reversed {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}
```